# Association em modelos Devexpress XPO

Tags: c#, modelo-relacional

Eu tenho um modelo para Municipio. Esse modelo pode ser referenciado por vários outros modelos (Cliente, Fornecedor, Transportadora, Vendedor...). Cada um desses modelos tem uma associação N:1 para Municipio, +/- assim:

```
public class Cliente: XPLiteObject {
  ...
  Municipio: fMunicipio;
  [Association]
  public Municipio Municipio {
    get { return fMunicipio; }
    set { SetPropertyValue("Municipio", ref fMunicipio, value); }
}
```

Segundo a documentação do XPO, eu devo declarar essa associação na outra ponta, no modelo Municipio, +/- assim:

```
public class Municipio: XPLiteObject {
  ...
  [Association]
  public XPCollection<Cliente> Clientes { 
    get { return GetCollection<Order>("Clientes"); }
  }     
}
```

Eu não quero (não gostaria) de declarar essa associação no modelo Municipio, porque eu não vou referenciar a lista de clientes a partir de Municipio. E também porque eu teria vários modelos referenciando Municipio, e não preciso obter a lista de nenhum deles a partir de Municipio. Outro agravante é que o modelo Municipio já está testado, e quando eu adicionar uma outro modelo referenciando Municipio, p.ex. Distribuidor, eu não quero alterar o modelo Municipio, acrescentando mais uma associação nele.

Minha dúvida é se a associação na outra ponta (Municipio) é obrigatório para cada modelo associado (Cliente, Vendedor...), ou se posso manter a referência só no modelo que mantém a relação. E, caso seja obrigatório, se devo nomear cada uma das associações para desambiguar as referências, assim:

```
public class Municipio: XPLiteObject {
  ...
  [Association("Cliente-Municipio)]
  public XPCollection<Cliente> Clientes { 
    get { return GetCollection<Order>("Clientes"); }
  }     
  [Association("Fornecedor-Municipio)]
  public XPCollection<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { 
    get { return GetCollection<Order>("Formecedores"); }
  }     
}

public class Cliente: XPLiteObject {
  ...
  Municipio: fMunicipio;
  [Association("Cliente-Municipio)]
  public Municipio Municipio {
    get { return fMunicipio; }
    set { SetPropertyValue("Municipio", ref fMunicipio, value); }
}

public class Fornecedor: XPLiteObject {
  ...
  Municipio: fMunicipio;
  [Association("Fornecedor-Municipio)]
  public Municipio Municipio {
    get { return fMunicipio; }
    set { SetPropertyValue("Municipio", ref fMunicipio, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É obrigatório ter a associação nos dois lados do modelo, o `Xpo` inspeciona as duas pontas para saber o tipo de associação que foi feita.

O nome da associação geralmente é opcional, associações do tipo N:1 ele consegue resolver sozinho inspecionando os nomes das classes, neste caso ele só deve ter problemas no caso de você ter mais de uma associação entre os mesmos modelos.

O nome vai ser obrigatório no caso de associações do tipo N:N, e nestes casos eu geralmente defino também a propriedade `UseAssociationNameAsIntermediateTableName = true` na declaração da associação para ter um controle maior da criação das tabelas.

Comment: Se é OBRIGATÓRIO, vamos fazer, né? Acho trabalhoso, mas posso viver com isso :)

Comment: Você pode sempre criar templates de código para facilitar isso, vai depender da IDE e plugins usados, no meu caso uso o `CodeRush` e ele já vem com alguns templates que eu personalizei para ficar mais do meu gosto, caso use o `CodeRush` teste os templates `xpa` e `xpcl`